# form onSubmit method do not work in react.js

Tags: javascript

The form onSubmit method(_updateThing) is not fired in my react.js app.
The source code is like the following.
I think the problem is easy, but I spend lots of time to check it ,  can't solve it.Please help me. 
what is wrong with my code:

```
export default React.createClass({
  displayName: 'ThingContainer',
  statics: {
    load: function (context) {
      return ThingActions.getData(context);
    }
  },
  mixins: [ContextMixin, MaterialRebindMixin],
  getInitialState() {
    return getThings();
  },
  _updateThing(e) {
    alert(1);
    e.preventDefault();
  },
  _setChangedText(event) {
    alert('change');
  },
   render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <h2>Title</h2>
            </div>
            <form  onSubmit={this._updateThing}>
              <div >
                <Label htmlFor="changeQuantity" text="" />
                <Input id="changeQuantity" name="changeQuantity" type="text" onChange={this._setChangedText}  />
              </div>
              <div className="form-footer">
                <div style={{float: 'right'}}>
                  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

I changed "form onSubmit={this._updateThing}" into "form onSubmit={this._updateThing.bind(this)}", but nothing changed.

I also using Chrome dev console to check html source,onSubmit method(_updateThing) is not shown in the html source.
[Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T8sc.png)

Thanks in advances.

Comment: Are your other event handlers working?

Comment: onChange method(_setChangedText) is also not fired in my react.js ,getInitialState method worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKay,I found the reason!
I am using server side rendering(React.renderToString) to render the HTML for the component.
So the component is only rendered, but not mounted, so any methods related to mounting are not called.

Detail:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdomserver.rendertostring

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the context of `this` is not being preserved. If you are using `React.createClass`, `this` is automatically bound ([source](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding)) which may throw you for a loop if you are a React dev moving to ES6 classes. With ES6 class constructor syntax, this is not the case and you must bind your own methods when appropriate. The most common way of doing this would be to `bind(this)` within your JSX.

For example, instead of
`onSubmit={this._updateThing}`

try
`onSubmit={this._updateThing.bind(this)}`

Comment: hi, Damon. Thank you for answer.I tried what you said, but nothing change. I also checked using chrome dev console, onSubmit method is not shown in the html source.

Comment: There is warning message after adding the bind method:Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call.

Comment: Hey @Ryu. Does it fix your problem? If so we have an interesting conundrum don't we.

Comment: Still not, yeah we have an conundrum.